# Add ID to image on drop only if ID not previously set using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to add an ID to an image when it is being dropped and only if the image has the title Router. I already figured this out but the problem is that every time a router is being dropped on the div, the ID of all the currently dropped routers are being modified too.

For example if I have 3 routers on the div, the count will be 3 and all the routers will have its ID set as R3 which I don't want.

So my question is, how can I set the ID only if the image doesn't previously have an ID?

**CODE:**

```
$('#droppable').on("drop", function () {
    var selectrouter = $('img[title="Router"]');

    numrouter = selectrouter.length;

    if((selectrouter.attr('id').length == 0)) { //what I tried to verify if ID is already set but not working
        selectrouter.attr('id', 'R' + (numrouter));
        console.log(numrouter);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attr()` will return `undefined` if it's not there. You are checking the length of that, which doesn't exist. You can just check the truthiness of it.

Instead of:

```
if((selectrouter.attr('id').length == 0)){
```

Try:

```
if(!selectrouter.attr('id')){
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I tried it and the condition seems to work but now the count of numrouter stays as zero. It's not getting the value assigned to it.

Comment: Have you checked that your selector is bringing back the number of elements you are expecting? Try printing `selectrouter` to console, is it showing what you expect?

Comment: With the console.log I get the correct value but somehow it's not being passed when I'm setting the ID. Actually numrouter finds all the images which have their title as Router.

Comment: Well I checked it again and the part of the code inside the condition to check whether the ID is set is perhaps wrong because the console.log inside it is not being accessed.

Comment: I just tested with my method and it worked great for me. Are you setting breakpoints and stepping through? Could you get a jsfiddle going?

Comment: Yep I am but somehow it's just not working. I got it to work using this if(!selectrouter.is('R' + numrouter-1)) to verify whether the id was already set. Thanks for your help cheers.